# SQL: How to get distinct values out of string_Agg() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following code

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT(p.ID) AS ID
    , PIT.Code AS Code
    , year(PT.Date) AS Year
FROM fact.PreT PT
INNER JOIN dim.ProdIType PIT 
    ON PIT.ProdITypeSKey = PT.ProdITypeSKey
INNER JOIN dim.Proudct P
    ON P.ProductSKey = pt.ProductSKey
WHERE p.ID = '15'
GROUP BY p.ID, PIT.Code, PT.Year
```

returns the following:

[image: Table with Codes]

I have reconfigured my script to add aggregate and group the codes by id and year, however duplicates are spotted. Code and output below:

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT(p.ID) AS ID
    , string_agg(PIT.Code, ',') AS Code
    , year(PT.Date) AS Year
FROM fact.PreT PT
INNER JOIN dim.ProdIType PIT 
    ON PIT.ProdITypeSKey = PT.ProdITypeSKey
INNER JOIN dim.Proudct P
    ON P.ProductSKey = pt.ProductSKey
WHERE p.ID = '15'
GROUP BY p.ID, PT.Year
```

Result:

[image: Incorrect Output]

Desired output - distinct and ordered code ascending:

[image]

Can someone explain why string_acc is duplicating codes? how should I tackle this issue?

Comment: can you provide sample data of all three individual tables for id=15?

Comment: Seems like a subquery is what you need, but impossible to know without sample data.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it is basically `GROUP BY allcolumns`

Comment: @Charlieface - thanks for the clarification. I guess reading online material such as this [link] https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-sql-count-distinct-function/#:~:text=This%20article%20explores%20SQL%20Count,SQL%20table%20with%20multiple%20conditions. doesn't help (they name distinct and count as functions).

Comment: That article is a complete horror show: they conflate `DISTINCT` and `COUNT(DISTINCT` and then pretend that in both of those instances there is a function call, which there is not. Also a temp table just to find the number of distinct pairs of values, could have just been a subquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subquery it and group again. Note that `DISTINCT` is not a function, it acts over the whole resultset, and is the same as grouping by all column.

```sql
SELECT 
      ID
    , string_agg(Code, ',') AS Code
    , [Year]
FROM (
    SELECT
          p.ID
        , PIT.Code AS Code
        , year(PT.Date) AS Year
    FROM fact.PreT PT
    INNER JOIN dim.ProdIType PIT 
        ON PIT.ProdITypeSKey = PT.ProdITypeSKey
    INNER JOIN dim.Proudct P
        ON P.ProductSKey = pt.ProductSKey
    WHERE p.ID = '15'
    GROUP BY p.ID, year(PT.Date), PIT.Code
) p
GROUP BY p.ID, PT.Year;
```

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface. This is a good answer. I think it would be great if you could please add explanations on how the two group by statements work and why the string_agg function would not return the desired result if used in a single query without a subquery. :)

Comment: Because OP effectively wants `STRING_AGG(DISTINCT Code, ',')` which is not supported at the moment. So you need to group by `Code` as well first, in order to get distinct `Code` per each `ID, Year` pair, then you can aggregate.